# how to show nivo-slider pagination in reverse/right to left order for arabic site?

Tags: javascript, css, nivo-slider

I am using nivo-slider on a arabic site. Now problem is the pagination need to look like 8765 instead of 1,2,3,4

how I can http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/'s pagination got it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try overriding float:left to float:right on the nivo-control DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

try adding these styles in your head tag, after the nivo-slider.css

```
.nivo-controlNav nivo-control{
float: right;
}
```